# How to tell Rails to work with the production database (rather than development one) when deploying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment

I'm trying to upload my Rails 3 application to real production environment. (The application works perfectly on my local machine).

When I run **rails c** I got the following error:

```
/home/misha_moroshko/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:62:in `establish_connection': development database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
        from /home/misha_moroshko/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:55:in `establish_connection'
        from /home/misha_moroshko/.gems/gems/activerecord-3.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:59
        from /home/misha_moroshko/.gems/gems/activesupport-3.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
```

How should I tell Rails that it should work with the production database rather than the development one ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set the RAILS_ENV environment variable first, or pass it to the rails c command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```

OR

```
rails c production
```

Answer (score 4):

what's in your database.yml? it should have a production setting and you'll need to tell rails you want to run it in production:

```
rails c production
```

Answer (score 1):

This depends greatly on the 'environment' you are deploying to. For Apache and Passenger, one would set:

```
# conf/passenger.conf
RailsEnv production
RackEnv production
```